# How to get the direction of roads in osmnx for finding shortest path for an emergency vehicle like ambulance

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shortest-path, osmnx

I am writing a code for shortest path with multiple heuristics for emergeency vehicles dispatchment like ambulances, I am using osmnx module and created an undirected weighted graph. I wanted to add a negative weight to edges if the road is one way and the direction in which the vehicle is going is oppositee of the direction of road but, I am not able to find that the vehicle is travelling in which direction with respect to direction of road so, I am unable to add a heuristic for that. There is no real ambulance so, it is not like I can use gps.

I tried to look at the different attributes of the graph that I got from osmnx. I thought that by looking at the edges, I can take the first coordinate as the starting and the seccond as the ending  and using that I thought I can get the directon but, there is the attribute 'reversed' whose significance I don't understand. It says something like if the attribute is true then, the edge is in the opposite direction of the OSM way, what does that even mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> there is the attribute 'reversed' whose significance I don't understand. It says something like if the attribute is true then, the edge is in the opposite direction of the OSM way, what does that even mean?

To answer this question: OpenStreetMap ways are defined by nodes in a certain order. If the way is bidirectional (that is, it allows two-way traffic), OSMnx models it with two reciprocal directed edges, one pointing in each direction. The `reversed` attribute indicates if this specific edge's nodes are in the reverse order of the original OpenStreetMap way's nodes. This allows using order-dependent attributes (such as lane directions). See [also](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/814).